# Can I kill an indestructible creature with damage and -1/-1?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-indestructible

If a indestructible creature is a 3/3 and I block that creature with a 2/2 then I give the indestructible creature a -1/-1 will the indestructible creature die?

Comment: Will the indestructible creature die?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I kill an indestructible creature with -X/-X and sufficient damage marked on it?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/31995/can-i-kill-an-indestructible-creature-with-x-x-and-sufficient-damage-marked-on)

Answer (score 4):

Don't confuse reduced toughness with damage. Damage gets marked on a creature, but it doesn't reduce its toughness.

The 3/3 takes two damage, remaining a 3/3. then you reduce it's power and toughness with the -1/-1. It is now a 2/2 with two damage marked on it. However it is indestructible so this is not sufficient to kill it. You would have to give it -3/-3  for example (reduce its toughness by 3)

> 702.12. Indestructible
>
> 702.12a. Indestructible is a static ability.
> 702.12b. A permanent with indestructible can't be destroyed. Such permanents aren't destroyed by lethal damage, and they ignore the state-based action that checks for lethal damage.
> 702.12c. Multiple instances of indestructible on the same permanent are redundant.

Answer (score 3):

No. Once damage has been dealt, the indestructable creature is a 2/2 with 2 damage on it. That means it has lethal damage, but that doesn't mean anything for an indestructable creature:

> 702.12b A permanent with indestructible can’t be destroyed. Such permanents aren’t destroyed by lethal damage, and they ignore the state-based action that checks for lethal damage (see rule 704.5g).

So you need to either lower the toughness of the creature further (to 0 or lower) or remove the indestructable ability from the creature. Damage isn't helping here at all.